# Inverse clause IN Named Query Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, named-query, in-clause

I need to acomplish something like this:

```
@NamedQuery (
   name="getEmployees",
   query="select object(em) from Employee em
          where (
              :workingGroup in em.listOfWorkingGroup1 or
              :workingGroup in em.listOfWorkingGroup2
          )"
)
```

I could get this to work.

I have 2 lists in an entity called `Employee` that represent groups of work.

And I want to get all the employees that have one particular workingGroup in one of their 2 lists of workingGroups. (`workingGroup` is a class, and `listOfWorkingGroup1` and `listOfWorkingGroup1` are Lists of `workingGroup`)

How could I manage to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you are trying to achieve it is a little confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `MEMBER OF`

```
select object(em) from Employee em where :workingGroup member of em.listOfWorkingGroup1 or :workingGroup member of em.listOfWorkingGroup2
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you need 15 reputation points for vote up privilege, but you can accept the answer instead (check mark).